# How should i bind viewList in android studio using Fragment and ViewModel class?

Tags: java, android

I want to create binding for **listView** named (id) **list** i was able to bind **textView**, but i have no idea how to bind list. Below i provide file i am working on. Is there any tutorial/docs how to works with ViewModel/fragment design patterns.

### BillingDataFragment.java

```
public class BillingDataFragment extends Fragment {

    private FragmentBillingDataBinding binding;

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        BillingDataViewModel billingDataViewModel =
                new ViewModelProvider(this).get(BillingDataViewModel.class);

        binding = FragmentBillingDataBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
        View root = binding.getRoot();

        final TextView textView = binding.textGallery;
        billingDataViewModel.getText().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), textView::setText);

        final ListView listView = binding.list;
        billingDataViewModel.getList().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), listView);

        return root;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        binding = null;
    }
}
```

### BillingDataViewModel:

```
public class BillingDataViewModel extends ViewModel {

    private final MutableLiveData<String> mText;

    private final MutableLiveData<ArrayList<String>> listItems;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;


    public BillingDataViewModel() {
        listItems = new MutableLiveData<>();
        mText = new MutableLiveData<>();
        mText.setValue("This is billing data fragment");
    }

    public LiveData<String> getText() {
        return mText;
    }

    public LiveData<ArrayList<String>> getList() {
        return listItems;
    }
}
```